# Cluster faces into groups

Tags: cluster-computing, grouping, cluster-analysis, face

The data:

2328568501515627770 2328529760910617771 100.0

2328529760910617771 2328568501515627770 100.0

2328529760910617771 2328530052968393930 99.976524

2328529760910617771 2328514835899260501 99.69356

2328529760910617771 2328515153726841781 98.76936

2328529760910617771 2328515132252005201 98.741165

2328529760910617771 2328515149431874457 98.6116

2328529760910617771 2328515158021809084 98.47021

2328529760910617771 2328515145136907144 98.156456

2328529760910617771 2328515089302332012 97.53229

2328529760910617771 2328515153726841775 97.449005

2328568501515627770 2328530052968393930 99.976524

2328530052968393930 2328529760910617771 99.976524

2328530052968393930 2328568501515627770 99.976524

2328530052968393930 2328514835899260501 99.68713

2328530052968393930 2328515132252005201 98.70858

2328530052968393930 2328515158021809084 98.612816

2328530052968393930 2328515153726841781 98.59485

2328530052968393930 2328515149431874457 98.43197

2328530052968393930 2328515145136907144 98.12278

2328530052968393930 2328515089302332012 97.5466

2328530052968393930 2328515153726841775 97.299934

2328515153726841775 2328568501515627770 97.44901

2328515153726841775 2328530052968393930 97.299934

2328515153726841775 2328514835899260501 97.28116

2328515153726841775 2328515149431874457 96.93521

First column is face id

Second column is matched face id

Third column is similarity score

EDIT: How can I apply hierarchical clustering on the above dataset.

Answer (score 0):

All similarities are way larger than 80%.

So everything is one cluster.

Comment: I have edited the question. My intention was to how can I apply hierarchical clustering on the above dataset.

Comment: Just do it. Load the data into a matrix, call the clustering function for a *similarity*.